# Identity Principle type question: Prove that $f=g$

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

While reading a complex analysis textbook the following assertion came up

> Since $f,g:D\equiv D(a,r) \to \mathbb{C}$ are analytic and injective functions such that $f(D)=g(D)$, $f(a)=g(a)$ and $f'(a)=g'(a)$ then $f=g$.

I do not think this follows directly! To prove it I think we need to use the Identity Principle. What I did is take a sequence $(z_n)_n \subset D $ such that $z_n \neq a$ and $z_n \to a$, then for each $n$ there exist $w_n \neq a$ such that $f(z_n)=g(w_n)$. By injectivity and since $f(a)=g(a)$, it follows that also $w_n \to a$. Now I am trying to use the condition $f'(a)=g'(a)$ to see that $z_n=w_n$ for infinitely many $n$'s and hence by the Identity Principle $f=g$. However this argumentation seems to lead nowhere.

Any help is very appreciated, perhaps there is a much more simple argument that do not uses anything that I have thought so far.

Comment: Why would you need a $w_n$ for $g$? Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't $f(z_n)=g(z_n)$ and not $f(z_n)=g(w_n)$?

Comment: @Scounged $w_n$ is needed. $f$ and $g$ have the same image, but *a priori* need not be the same function.

Comment: @Scounged Since $f(D)=g(D)$, for each $f(z_n)=x \in f(D)$ there exist a $w_n \in D$ such that $g(w_n)=x=f(z_n)$. What I want to prove is that in fact $z_n=w_n$ for an infinite numbers of $n$´s and thus that $f$ and $g$ coincides in a set with an accumulation point in $D$.

Comment: Consider $f^{-1}\circ g$, which is an analytic bijection from a disk to itself which fixes the center.  What do you know about such functions?

Comment: @LeoSera it seems like I confused the terminology there a bit. English isn't my first language, and I assumed that the "Identity Principle" was the English name for the theorem where you have two analytic functions that are equal in every point of a sequence with an accumulation point in $D$, for some reason. Apparently that theorem is called something else, but I can't seem to find the correct name for it.

Comment: @Scounged I know that theorem as the Identity Principle, and it is exactly the theorem that I am trying to apply. And don't worry, I am also not a native english speaker, I struggle my self time to time to find the names of the theorems I want.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks for your comment!! I see that $f^{-1}\circ g$ is an analytic bijection from $D$ to $D$ and with $a$ as a fixed point, however I do not now much about that functions, I guess that $f^{-1}\circ g$ must be the identity map, but why?

Comment: @LeoSena Ah, ok I see now. Thanks for the clarification. I must have misunderstood a bit when I read the question and didn't understand you wanted to prove the existence of such a sequence. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Next, use the [Schwarz lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma).  After that, you can use the derivative condition.

Comment: The hypotheses imply that you can let $F=f\circ g^{-1}$, and then $F:D\to D$...

Comment: Thanks a lot @MichaelBurr . I guess I was stubborn on using the Identity principle that I forgot Schwarz Lemma !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality we can assume $D$ to be the unit disk ($a=0$). Then $g^{-1}\circ f$ maps to unit disk to itself fixing zero. Now the Schwarz lemma says
$$
|(g^{-1}\circ f)'(0)|=|(g^{-1})'\circ f(0)||f'(0)|\leq 1.
$$
Differentiating $g^{-1}\circ g=z$ yields $(g^{-1})'\circ g\cdot g'=1$. Plug zero into this to show
$$
(g^{-1})'\circ f(0)=(g^{-1})'\circ g(0)=\frac{1}{g'(0)}=\frac{1}{f'(0)},
$$
which means $(g^{-1}\circ f)'(0)=1$. Now the Schwarz lemma shows further that $g^{-1}\circ f(z)=az$ for some $|a|=1$, $f(z)=g(az)$, $f'(z)=ag'(az)$, and so $a=1$ by plugging in $z=0$. I believe this to be correct. I typed it up rather quickly.

Comment: Now I just feel stupid, but doesn't $g\circ f^{-1}:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$? $f^{-1}:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow D$, and $g:D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, so shouldn't it be the other way around(first take $g$, and then $f^{-1}$)? It shouldn't really make a difference, but I just got a bit confused, as I thought that $u\circ v(z)=u(v(z))$. But maybe I got it backwards.

Comment: Blake It is correct, thank you. @Scounged since $f: D \to f(D)$ and $g:D \to g(D)=f(D)$, thus $f^{-1}:f(D) \to D$ and then indeed $f^{-1}\circ g : D \to f(D) \to D$, analogously $g^{-1}\circ f : D \to D$

Comment: I mixed up a few things I think, but I believe I fixed it. Need to slow it down

Comment: @Blake it also worked for me with $f^{-1}\circ g $

Comment: @LeoSera Yes it shouldn't matter. Pick your favorite!

Comment: @Blake Doesn't Schwarz Lemma imply that $(g^{-1}\circ f)(z)=a z $ and hence $f(z)=g(az)$, how do we get $f(z)=ag(z)$?

Comment: @Leo Sera You could always just derive that: $f'(z)=ag'(az)$. $f'(0)=g'(0)$ so plugging in $z=0$ shows $a=1$. There are probably other ways to go about it.

Comment: @Blake Thanks again !! Now it is complete !!